# How to properly make use of TestContext.Properties

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

I need to access `TestContext.Properties` before a `TestMethod` so the test can receive the correct environment to test.

---

The contents of my `test.runsettings`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
      <Parameter name="colegio" value="7" />
    </TestRunParameters>
```

As you can see, the file only contains one parameter, called `colegio (school)`

---

This are the contents of `TestBase.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using InfraestructureSelenium.Helper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using InfraestructureSelenium.Configuration.Enumerados;

namespace TestSelenium
{
    [DeploymentItem("chromedriver.exe")]
    [DeploymentItem("IEDriverServer.exe")]
    [DeploymentItem("phantomjs.exe")]
    [DeploymentItem("geckodriver.exe")]
    [TestClass]
    public class TestBase
    {
        protected TestBase()
        { }

        public TestBase(int id = (int)ColegioEnum.ColegioDemoMovilidad2_Supervisor)
        {
            DiccionarioCompartido = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            SeleniumHelper = new HelperSelenium(id, WebDriverSelector.ObtenerWebDriver());
        }

        public TestBase(HelperSelenium seleniumHelper, Dictionary<string, string> diccionarioCompartido = null)
        {
            SeleniumHelper = seleniumHelper;
        }

        public HelperSelenium SeleniumHelper { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> DiccionarioCompartido { get; set; }

        public void CloseBrowser()
        {
            SeleniumHelper.Quit();
        }

        #region Configuración Test

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitializeTest()
        {

        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanupTest()
        {
            SeleniumHelper.Quit();
        }

        #endregion
        }
    }
```

---

As you can see, `public TestBase(int id = (int)ColegioEnum.ColegioDemoMovilidad2_Supervisor)` receives an argument, which corresponds to the `colegio` environment I want to test. If no `colegio` is passed as an argument, the default one will be `ColegioEnum.ColegioDemoMovilidad2_Supervisor`

However, when I try to instantiate `TestContext`in a `TestClass`, like this:

```cs
[TestClass]
    public class GenerarBoletinDeClase : TestBase
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        private static TestContext _testContext;

        [TestInitialize]
        public static void SetupTests(TestContext testContext)
        {
            _testContext = testContext;
        }

        public GenerarBoletinDeClase() : base((int)TestContext.Properties["colegio"]) { }
```

The following error appears: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`

Any help is appreciated as I've given this problem a lot of time and I couldn't progress any further.

Comment: Is that the entire error dump? It looks like you cut and pasted just the part you think helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @Peska for providing the code in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51367231/5364231

---

So, finally what I did was add the following code to the class `TestBase`:

```
public class TestBase
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    public static int Colegio { get; set; }

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext TestContext)
    {
        Colegio = int.Parse(TestContext.Properties["colegio"].ToString()); // colegio is equal 7 in here
    }

    public TestBase()
    {
        SeleniumHelper = new HelperSelenium(Colegio, WebDriverSelector.ObtenerWebDriver());
        DiccionarioCompartido = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
```

The decorator `[AssemblyInitialize]` is necessary, `[ClassInitialize]` and `[TestInitialize]` will not work, I believe because the TestContext has not been instantiated yet.

After that, make sure that you have configured a `Test Settings File` by going to `Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings File`, the file must be named `*.runsettings`

With that, everything should be set up for `TestContext.Properties` to read from your test settings file

Answer (score 3):

You have to fix few things:

- TestInitialize method cannot be static and it shouldn't have any parameters
- You will need static method with ClassInitialize attribute and TestContext as parameter
- TestContext in your test class cannot be static

After that, you can access whatever properties you want in any unit tests. Here is an example:

```
[TestClass]
public class GenerarBoletinDeClase
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    public static int Colegio { get; set; }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        Colegio = int.Parse(testContext.Properties["colegio"].ToString()); // colegio is equal 7 in here
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        int tempColegio = int.Parse(this.TestContext.Properties["colegio"].ToString()); // colegio is equal 7 in here
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        int colegio = int.Parse(this.TestContext.Properties["colegio"].ToString()); // colegio is equal 7 in here as well

        Assert.AreEqual(7, Colegio);
        Assert.AreEqual(7, colegio);
        Assert.AreEqual(colegio, Colegio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Peska,  

I've added your code but now I am receiving  
  
>An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in  >SeleniumTest.dll but was not handled in user code  
>  
>Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Make sure to select your `test.runsettings` file. Go to Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings File.

Comment: it **finally** works!

Thanks a lot for your help, I've dedicated a lot of time to this and I was ready to give up. I've posted an answer on how I made it work, as the code had to be slightly tunned. However, it was thanks to your code.

Answer (score 2):

To use the file : test.runsettings
1-You have to Manually select the run stting file
In the IDE, select Test > Configure Run Settings > Select Solution Wide runsettings
File, and then select the .runsettings file.

2-Set a build property
you have specify the run settings file for the project by the property : RunSettingsFilePath

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#testrunparameters), you don't need to assign TestContext for it to be filled. It automagically gets assigned before each TestInitialize call. From there, you can access your properties defined in *.runsettings through the property.

In summary, simply add a TestContext typed property named TestContext and MS Test will fill it at runtime.